# java verifying variables from textfile

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

I have this problem when reading from a text file where the credentials are separated with new lines, like new paragraphs, which I don't know how to read them. The following is my login button codes:

```
private class Login implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent Login){  
        Boolean login = false;
        file = new File("Member Details.txt");
        try {
            read = new Scanner(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(BTRSMain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        String user = read.next();
        String pass = read.next();
        if(loginpage.UsernameTB.getText().equals(user) && loginpage.PasswordTB.getText().equals(pass)){
           login = true;}
        if(login)
        {
            loginpage.frame.setVisible(false);
            mainmenupage.frame.setVisible(true);
        }
        else
        {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect username or password! Please re-enter!");
           loginpage.UsernameTB.setText("");
           loginpage.PasswordTB.setText("");
        }
        }
    }
```

After the user sign up, the member details, which is the username and password would be saved in the text files, each in a new line, [the text file image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiJYe.png), in the login page, the first username and password can be read, but later that, the second username and password can't be read, how could I do that? how do I read that code in new lines?

The text file's text is like this:
The first line(the first username): lulu
The second line(the first password): lili
The third line(the second username): lili
The fourth line(the second password): lulu

it can read the first username and password, but not the second username and password.

Comment: Please show the text file content as text not as an image. What is the exact format of this file? Is it for only one username/password or do you store multiple username/password combinations in it?

Comment: use a while loop..

Answer (score 1):

You're just reading a single username-password pair. You need to read the entire file. E.g., if we keep the current design of reading the file each time, you could do something like this (I separated the login checking logic to another method. The original method can call it and pop up the relevant message):

```
private boolean canLogin(String user, String password) {
    try (Scanner read = new Scanner(new File("Member Details.txt"))) {
        while (read.hasNext()) {
            String readUser = read.next();
            String readPassword = read.next(); // Assume the file is well-formed

            // If it's the right user, check the password
            // If not, continue reading the file
            if (user.equals(readUser)) {
                return password.equals(readPassowrd);
            }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(BTRSMain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return false;
}
```